# How does the frequentist approach to probability estimation work when the number of outcomes is greater than 2?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, estimation, inference, frequentist

I've read [Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair) and I'm trying to find a resource which generalizes the frequentist approach to the case where there are $k$ distinct outcomes and $n$ trials. Can someone point me in the right direction?

In other words:

- I have a sample space with $k$ outcomes (and the probability of each outcome is unknown)
- I conduct $n$ trials and estimate the probability of each outcome as $\frac{k_i}{n}$ where $k_i$ is one of the $k$ outcomes (as is done in the frequentist interpretation)

How do I relate the error in my estimations to the number of trials conducted?

Comment: Check out the multinomial distribution

Comment: @DemetriPananos I've taken a look and am pleased to find that MLE of multinomial distributions produces an estimator that matches what I've written above. What I've failed to find is a simple exposition of how it relates to error/confidence (like the Wikipedia article does). Any hints?

Comment: That article mixes frequentist and bayesian approaches.  I'll assume you are a frequentest for now.  We know that the MLE is asymptotically unbiased and consistent, so with more data we can be more confident.  In order to quantify this, you could look at the marginal confidence sets for each parameter.